# Seemingly conflicting conditions for definitions of a discrete random varable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, definition

In *Probability: An Introduction* by Grimmett and Welsh, there are two conditions laid out for the definition of a discrete random variable.

**Def:** A discrete random variable on $(\Omega, \Sigma, \Pr)$ is a mapping $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that:

1. The image of $X$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb R$.
2. (all) $x \in \mathbb R$: $X^{-1}(x) \in \Sigma$.

The first part makes sense to me; we have a function who's domain is $\Omega$ (the event space) and range is some subset of $\mathbb R$. The codomain is $\mathbb R$. The second, however, is confusing me. It seems to be saying that every element of $\mathbb R$ has a preimage in $\Omega$, which seems to mean that the function is mapping all elements of $\mathbb R$ (so the range is not a proper subset), and which would also mean that the range is not countable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider for example a probability space $\Omega=[0,\,1]$ with some sigma-algebra $\Sigma$ - say, let it be $\Sigma=\{\varnothing, \Omega, [0,\,0.5],(0.5,\,1]\}$ and a discrete random variable
$$
X(\omega)=\begin{cases} 7, & 0\leq \omega \leq 0.5,\cr 13, & 0.5 < \omega \leq 1.\end{cases}
$$
Then the set of all possible values of $X$ is finite and consists of two values. Consider preimage of arbitrary point of $\mathbb R$. Say, $$X^{-1}(7)=[0,\,0.5]\in \Sigma,$$
$$X^{-1}(13)=(0.5,\,1]\in \Sigma,$$
$$X^{-1}(5)=\varnothing\in \Sigma,$$
$$X^{-1}(\pi)=\varnothing\in \Sigma,$$
$$X^{-1}(0.2)=\varnothing\in \Sigma$$
and so on.

The preimage of a set in codomain is some set in the domain. When we write $X^{-1}(x)$, we really mean that we take preimage of a one-point set $\{x\}$, so it is $X^{-1}(\{x\})$. It is customary to omit unnecessary parentheses. And the preimage of a set is the collection of all values in the domain s.t. $X$ of this values belongs to this set. If $X$ cannot take values in this set, then the preimage is empty and belongs to sigma-algebra by definition.

Answer (score 1):

$X^{-1}(x)=\{\omega: X(\omega) =x\}$ is the empty set if $x$ is not in the range of $X$ and empty set belongs to $\Sigma$.